# read multi-array from plist

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I can't get it work to have the 8 items from the plist below.
I have a plist "settings.plist". Now I wan't from vragen -> category `(self.catagorie - 1)` -> question. The 8 items. But the array keeps empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instellingen.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *instellingen = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *vragen = [instellingen objectForKey:@"vragen"];

NSArray *cata = [vragen objectAtIndex: (self.catagorie-1)];
NSArray *question = [cata objectAtIndex: 0];
NSLog(@"count: %i", [question count]);
```

Plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>vragen</key>
    <array>
        <array> <--catagorydata
            <array> <-- questiondata
                <string>vraag</string>
                <string>A</string>
                <string>B</string>
                <string>C</string>
                <string>D</string>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>standaard</string>
                <string></string>
            </array>
            <array>
                <string>vraag2</string>
                <string>A</string>
                <string>B</string>
                <string>C</string>
                <string>D</string>
                <string>1</string>
                <string>afbeelding</string>
                <string>afbeelding.jpg</string>
            </array>
        </array>
    </array>
    <key>firstBoot</key>
    <true/>
    <key>regelAtRuntime</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Is the mutable dictionary that you get nil (instellingen == nil)?

Comment: when I count the root I get 2 as result. When I want to go deeper I get 0 as result.

Comment: Shouldn't `[vragen objectAtIndex:self.catagorie - 1]` and `[cata objectAtIndex:0]` be swapped? (along with the necessary modifications, of course...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this line

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instellingen.plist"]; ?
```

should be

```
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
```

I also had to delete these from the dictionary:

```
<--catagorydata
<-- questiondata
```

Besides the two things above, there is nothing wrong with your code or your dictionary.
After making those changes I tested your code and the output I got was:

```
tester[69637:c07] size of dict 3  
tester[69637:c07] count: 8
```

which is correct according to the .plist file

So your problem is at the first 4 lines. Make sure your file is in Documents directory (use something like the following code to see whats going wrong)

```
    NSLog(@"Path : %@",path);
```

I copied the file in the project folder (because I used the simulator) and used the following code and everything worked fine

```
NSBundle* b=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL* path1=[b URLForResource:@"settings" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *instellingen = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:path1];

NSLog(@"size of dict %d",[instellingen count]);

NSArray *vragen = [instellingen objectForKey:@"vragen"];

NSArray *cata = [vragen objectAtIndex: 0];
NSArray *question = [cata objectAtIndex: 0];
NSLog(@"count: %i", [question count]);
```

Comment: Thank you, the main problem was that the plist in the document folder was out-dated. I had to remove the app and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick read, but looks like you have an array of "categoryData" items, that contains an array of questionData items; questionData items are strings.

```
NSArray *vragen = [instellingen objectForKey:@"vragen"]; // count = 1
NSArray *cata = [vragen objectAtIndex: (self.catagorie-1)]; // count = 2
NSString *question = [cata objectAtIndex: 0];
```

Recommend you add some breakpoints and look at your data.  OR, NSLog(@"data = %@", cata); etc.